# How to append dynamic .next() function to jQuery object

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a comment section with comments and replies. After I delete one comment I want all replies to be deleted as well. The only one approach that is in my mind is to use this:

```
$(this).closest(".comment-container").next('.add-reply-container').next('.reply-comment-container')
```

I want to do this in a `while` loop until all replies are deleted, but how I can attach a dynamic `.next('.reply-comment-container')` to my object?

HTML

```
<div class="comment-container" id="number">
  <div class="comment-title">
    <span class="comment-creator-name"> Author Name </span> • now 2 minute
  </div>
  <div class="comment-text">
    Question
  </div>
  <div class="comment-bottom">
    <button class="comment-reply-button">Raspunde</button>
    <button class="delete-comment-button">Sterge</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="add-reply-container">
  <textarea class="add-reply-textbox" placeholder="Scrie o intrebare..">
                                    </textarea>
  <button class="add-reply-button">Trimite</button>
</div>
<div class="reply-comment-container\">
  <div class="comment-title">
    <span class="comment-creator-name"> Reply Author Name </span> • now one minute
  </div>
  <div class="comment-text">
    BLA BLA
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To determine how this code can be improved we need to see the HTML. It would however, make sense to have the replies as child elements of the parent comment. That way you can delete all replies with a comment, just by calling `remove()` on it.

Comment: The correct answer depends on your HTML structure. So if you could include the HTML code that would be great.

Comment: Sorry that took so much, but i formatted from ajax call in normal format, for a better view

Comment: Nobody can help a little bit ? I still did not solve the problem